# Pain in Back after lifting body

Tags: muscle, abdominals, back-pain, spine

I was doing decline bench press with dumb bells, and after exercise i put dumbbell on my chest and tried to lift my body but  middle back felt pain middle of thoracic , my body was not lifted enough for hip extension muscles to be activated, so why I got pain.

Which muslce got activated in back wrongly?

Was not abs supposed to lift my body initially?